# Update Table When Structured Reference Gets New Row

Tags: excel

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this one out. I have two tables: one is named `servers` and the other is called `breakdown`. `servers` is on an overview worksheet where we add a name to it when we get new staff or someone extra is working that week. We have a worksheet for everyday of the week with a breakdown of payments taken by type with the servers name as the left-most column.

Right now it's currently populated by structured cell reference to the overview worksheet, e.g., `Overview!B4`. I want to be able to have my Data tables `servers` and `breakdown` separate and when I add a new name to the `servers` table, it dynamically updates `breakdown` to add an additional row with the server name in the left-most column

```
| Servers |              | Server | Cash | Visa | ...
-----------              ----------------------------
|Billy-Joe|     -->      |        |      |      | 
|Peggy-Sue|     -->      |        |      |      | 
|Clancy   |     -->      |        |      |      |
```

Add a new name:

```
| Servers |              | Server | Cash | Visa | ...
-----------              ----------------------------
|Billy-Joe|              |Billy-Joe|      |      | 
|Peggy-Sue|              |Peggy-Sue|      |      | 
|Clancy   |              |Clancy   |      |      |
|Skeeter  |      -->     |Skeeter  |      |      |
```

All I can think of at the moment is have the cell in `breakdown` as `=Servers[@Servers]` but I need to have my table at a specific row in order to get the correct range of values. With this method, I have to manually go and tab at the end of the `breakdown` table in order for it to update.

Is there a non-Macro, non-VB way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the breakdown sheet(s) as (a) structured table, use a normal range so you can use this formula to populate the Server column (supposing your Servers table is named servers):

```
=servers[Servers]
```

providing the values in Servers are unique, or

```
=UNIQUE(servers[Servers])
```

If they might not be (for whatever reason).

In this gif, the first formula above is in cell A3 on the "Monday" sheet. You can see that as I add names to the Overview, they appear on Monday as well.

[image]

Comment: This is a great start, but my other issue is that I need formatting, I have sections below the breakdown that can't become an issue with spill arrays if they ever overlap. If I remove a name from the Overview, it doesn't remove the corresponding row from the breakdown. Do you know if this is possible in Excel with built-in functionality?

Comment: @Harben If you set it up as suggested, removing a name from Overview **will** remove it from breakdown.  Isn't that what you want?  And what does "formatting" have to do with this?  It would be better if you edit your original question to provide the missing information.